# Getting an element to display after clicking

Tags: html, css

I have a list that displays following clicking the menu. However, it disappears immediately unless you hold down your click. How can I get it to stay after clicking? Do I have to use javascript?

If I make the element menu:hover then it appears when hovering over, and it stays, but I want to be able to click the menu and the sub menu still stays appearing after it has been clicked.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
 height:1000px;
 width:100%;
 background:#FCF;
}
#first-div{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 background:#9CF;
}
#first-div img:hover{
 opacity:0.3;
}

#clear{
 clear:both;
 display:block;
 margin: 50px 0 50px 0;
}

#menu{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 background:#0C9;
 display:inline-block;
}

ul.nav-menu{
 display:inline;
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 display:none;
}

#menu:active ul.nav-menu{
 display:inline;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ns-3.css"/>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="first-div">
<img src="http://www.todayifoundout.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/african-elephant-bull.jpg" width="300" height="300"  alt=""/>
</div>

<div id="clear"></div>

<nav id="menu">
Menu
<ul class="nav-menu">
<li>text 1</li>
<li>text 2</li>
<li>text 3</li>
</ul>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may check this - https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/d3sgpcoy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `:focus` and `tabindex` for menu.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FCF;
}

#first-div {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #9CF;
}

#first-div img:hover {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

#clear {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  margin: 50px 0 50px 0;
}

#menu {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #0C9;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.nav-menu {
  display: inline;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
}

#menu:focus ul.nav-menu {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="first-div">
  <img src="http://www.todayifoundout.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/african-elephant-bull.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="" />
</div>
<div id="clear"></div>
<nav id="menu" tabindex="1">
  Menu
  <ul class="nav-menu">
    <li>text 1</li>
    <li>text 2</li>
    <li>text 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: wow that is interesting. can you please explain what tabindex is & why it's needed? I've never heard of that. and thank you!

Comment: and why is there a blue border around it after it is clicked?

Comment: tabindex specifies the block number to switch the focus between them by pressing tab. by default the ul-tag can not be focus, tabindex solves this problem. blue border is a outline, may be...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with some jquery.
Add this active class to your css. Remove the #menu:active ul.nav-menu selector.(p.s. i'm writting on a phone)

```
.active {
   display:inline;
 }
```

and then add this to a script tag or file:

```
$('#menu').click(function(){
    $('.nav-menu').toggleClass('active');
 });
```